# Python: creating a new window, accessing it's pixels and activating them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been thoroughly searching this forum, the internet, and pretty much everything. I want to be able to create a new graphics window in python without using something else, for a project in which I want specialized optimized for whatever a need without any other extra mumbo-jumbo, and understanding fully how it works. Anyways, I want to be able to access pixel by pixel of a new window without using tkinter/turtle, installations, or anything of the sort. Just basic, simple, pixel access of a new window. If this isn't possible, just let me know. I imagine the program could look something like this:

```
import NOTHING_AT_ALL_GRAPHICS_WISE
window.pixel(1,2,True)
```

I program in Python 3.6.3

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that can be done without some extra libraries. That's why those were written...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seek to accomplish isn't as simple as you might believe. Applications draw graphics on the screen largely with the help of calls to the graphics card API. Those API's can be complicated, as they should be, because all the graphics that you see on your screen, whether it be your browser GUI, to video playback, to your Starcraft II, has to use combinations of these calls to produce the beautiful and seamless graphics you see on your screen (graphics would NOT look good without use of the GPU).

However, not all manipulation of graphics has to be so complicated, and many languages/frameworks write wrappers around some of the graphics libraries that expose a simpler subset of the total functionality. Tkinter is a good example.

If you don't want to import ANYTHING, you will have to make the calls to the API yourself, and you're not in for a good time. Nobody does this nowadays for personal projects because it really is quite complicated. Also, Python is a very high-level language, and although it might expose the OS's system calls that you need, you're probably better off doing it in C.  Before you proceed, I suggest you read up on the fundamentals of computer graphics work. Here's a nice image that shows how OpenGL, a very popular graphics library, works.

[image]

Comment: yea thats what i said

Comment: @SuperStew yeah I see that now. noticed your comment only after I posted. oh well, a little explanation can't hurt

Comment: lol it was a good explanation, just keeping the mood light. Too many people here are so damn serious

Comment: @SuperStew true dat people are pretty uptight here sometimes. i like it for a change though, its nice to have a sanctity of seriousness on the internet.

Comment: @vasia Thanks so much. I really appreciate people like you taking time out of your day to help clueless people like me (lol). And oh boy, I guess I really should stop worrying about the complexity of my code and just use a damn library. It'll be the opposite of what I expected: it'll be less complicated. Thanks again, and sorry about the belated response. I've been busy with thanksgiving break.

Comment: @RobertoBassett yes, using a library will ultimately make your life easier. However, I understand your motivation for wanting to do the things the way you proposed. When I was starting out in CS/programming, I had a similar mindset. I didn't want to deal with libraries that people wrote, that forced me to learn their system first before I could do something. I just wanted to "DO" it. Like, instead of using a graphics library, I just wanna draw the pixels MYSELF. I totally get it :)

If what I said describes your mindset, you would love assembly - it's as close to the metal as possible!

Comment: @vasia I don't think I will be switching to a different language anytime soon, python is known for being very "readable" and having batteries included. Also, I'm too lazy to teach myself a new language. As of python, do you know a library I can download that'll be simple for what I'm trying to do? I tried pygame since this post and I can't do what I want to do with, and all the tutorials for it just talk about loading an image into the window. For my project, I just need to be able to set pixels. (P.S, you did guess my mindset.)

Comment: @RobertoBassett yeah haha I wasn't recommending that you pickup assembly for this project, I just meant that you would appreciate it because there are virtually no abstractions - it really is what it is.

_As far as pixel manipulation_, I can think of two simple options:
1) Using tkinter create squares/rectangles that are approximately pixel-sized.
2) Usng tkinter show an Image object, that you can directly manipulate and update. If you want a lot of pixels, for efficiency you could probably split it into multiple images, so that there's less to update each time you change something.

Comment: @RobertoBassett I don't know of any python libraries that contain some sort of window object that would directly expose a 2d grid of pixels, so my previous comment described ways of simulating that.

Comment: @vasia thanks. You're the only not passive-aggressive person on this site I've met so far. That's the reason this is the only post I'm not deleting. Also, I already solved my problem with turtle but I'll give Tkinter a try as well. I think turtle uses Tkinter or the other way around anyways. What would you suggest for me to learn more about _how_ python works

Comment: @RobertoBassett thanks, I appreciate it, and I'm sorry you feel that way about the website. StackOverflow is pretty awesome, and has helped me an uncountable amount of times, I only recently started trying to contribute myself. It may seem that some people on here have an "attitude", but that's really because they just want to maintain a certain level of quality on the questions and answers on the site. That requires some active moderation, which by some could definitely construed in a non-amicable way (especially if someone shits on a question you ask). So, I get where you're coming from.

Comment: @RobertoBassett however, please do not delete any of your posts, especially if you believe that there is someone who could possibly benefit from your question and its answers. It is very possible that most of the benefit from the answer to the question that you ask goes not to you, but to the many people who view your question and its answers over the years to come.

Comment: As far as learning more about _how_ python works, here are two articles I believe are a good place to start:

This is an answer to a question about python's internals:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/313254/how-does-the-python-runtime-actually-work

This is an article about understanding Python's execution
https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/

After reading those you should be informed enough to know what specifically to look into next. Have fun! Python is life

Comment: @vasia Oh I thought that they were just trying to be jackasses. Thanks for telling me though. I didn't realize that this was the mentality. Also, I'll take a look at those articles.

Comment: @vasia I'm ready to do this project, I want to know how. Where should I start? I want to do exactly what I said earlier. I'm making my own graphics library to do things at the lowest level. I've improved my python and realized that python is a terrible language for this, but I'm willing to put up with the difficulty and try.

Comment: If you want to make your own graphics library, you should really use C instead. I can't think of a good reason to use Python (except for making a wrapper for a library written in C). I would start by looking at OpenGL and seeing how it works. Look at the source, and try to trace the execution from some library function call that draws something on the screen, all the way to the system calls. You should also probably find out specifically what kind of graphics card you have, and read up on how to program for it. Spend a lot of time looking at how OpenGL works, it will help you understand it all

Comment: @vasia thanks. That's actually exactly what I'm trying to do. Most 3D graphics libraries today are vertex based, but my friend and Iwant to make a voxel-octree based 3D library. The best way to make this efficient is by skipping past the vertex based libraries (instead of making voxels out of verts) and doing it at a lower level. Also, I tried installing pyopengl on my computer but there was an error. I will find out what graphics card I have. And we will be doing path tracing at a lower level as well to try and speed it up.

Comment: @vasia I was able to successfully install pyOpenGL this time, and I located it, but now I have no idea where to look to see where it does it's lower level graphics "stuff".

Comment: @CoderBoy If your goal is to make a 3D graphics library, forget about Python for now. It is only going to complicate things because Python provides an abstraction to the stuff that you want to directly manipulate. So don't install pyOpenGL, install just OpenGL (without the "py" prefix). And to understand you don't even have to install it, just read the documentation and look at the source code. Also, this won't be easy. This will not be a quick "5 minute" analysis. This will take hours, or days before you really start to get whats going on.

Comment: @CoderBoy one implementation of OpenGL that you can take a look at is Mesa3D: https://www.mesa3d.org/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160464/discussion-between-coderboy-and-vasia).

Comment: @vasia Apparently there is I just moved it to the chatrooms... I didn't even know that. SO prompted me to move it to there.

Comment: @vasia try clicking the link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160464/discussion-between-coderboy-and-vasia

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want. Python has no way of changing a single pixel on the screen. This is the whole reason why such "mumbo jumbo" libraries exist: it's a complex problem that requires specialized libraries that know how each operating system works.